# Excel Formula linking

Tags: excel

Is it possible to link the text in the sheet to the formula. See picture for example. I would like the formula to updated in 2012-CLF1 because I have to create new sheets (next one would be 2013-CLF1) instead of updating individual formulas.

[image]

Comment: use INDIRECT, but it requires the target workbook to be open.

Comment: btw, hand-drawn circles and arrows generally gets you upvotes.